# Legendre polynomials in $L^2[-1,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I came across a problem that asked to show there's no proper subset of Legendre polynomials in $L^2[-1,1]$ that is complete. Since by Weierstrass Approximation Theorem, Legendre polynomials are complete in $L^2[-1,1]$, so my attempt so far is to show that the Legendre polynomials actually form a basis of $L^2[-1,1]$, then there won't be a proper subset. Am I thinking right? Any help or hint is appreciated.

Comment: In fact, the completeness of an orthonormal system is a necessary and sufficient condition for it to be a basis.

Comment: Legendre polynomials can't be an actual basis for $L^2$ (for cardinality reasons), they can only form a hilbert basis, which is somewhat different.

That being said,  if you show or already have shown that legendre polynomials are orthogonal for the usual scalar product, you're done here.

Comment: @thing So you mean that my idea is correct and I just need to show that legendre polynomials are orthogonal system, right?

Comment: If some proper subset of Legendre polynomials were complete, then this would be a basis. And this is impossible because the basis forms the system of all Legendre polynomials. Therefore you are right, you need to prove orthonormality.

Comment: @thing That makes sense, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have an orthonormal set $\{ e_n \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ in a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. If you remove $e_1$ from the set, then the remaining set cannot be complete because $e_1$ is orthogonal to the remaining set.